# Не срабатывает цикл в python

Tags: python, циклы, pandas, dataframe

Итак, есть исходный DataFrame, в нем всего 1 строка:

```
x1         x2
16,00   500,00
```

Есть второй DataFrame:

```
Ot  Do  Rating
-50000,00   0,20    0,1900
0,20    0,65    0,1400
0,65    0,80    0,1100
0,80    1,25    0,0900
1,25    1,50    0,0600
1,50    1,75    0,0500
1,75    2,00    0,0450
2,00    2,25    0,0360
2,25    2,50    0,0300
2,50    3,00    0,0200
3,00    4,25    0,0156
4,25    5,50    0,0138
5,50    6,50    0,0125
6,50    8,50    0,0100
8,50    50000,00    0,0075
```

Мой код:

```
rate = []
for z in range(1): 
    for k in range(14):
        t= (q[z])/((e[k]+0.02) * w[z])
        if r[k]>=t :
            rate.append(e[k])
```

где q - это x2, e - это rating, w-это x1, r - это Do во втором DF

Если все это посчитать, то получится такой список значений:

```
148,8095238
195,3125
240,3846154
284,0909091
390,625
446,4285714
480,7692308
558,0357143
625
781,25
877,8089888
924,556213
961,5384615
1041,666667
1136,363636
```

По сути единственно правильное значение здесь это последнее, ибо `1136,363636 < 50000`, поэтому цикл должен "вписать в список" последнее значение rating , то есть `0.0075` , но почему то он ничего не записывает. 
Помогите, где я ошибся?

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, корректный текст вашей программы, что-бы можно было воспроизвести ее работу. Фраза про "единственно правильное значение, которое меньше 50000" вообще непонятна, т.к. все приведенные значения меньше 50000.

Comment: Есть хороший способ - в любой непонятной ситуации выводи на печать промежуточные значения и смотри, что происходит. Ни разу еще не подводил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение:

```
def get_rating(val, rdf, formula):
    r = rdf.query(formula)
    if not r.empty:
        return r.iat[0, 2]
    else:
        return None

formula="Ot <= @val / (Rating+0.02) <= Do"
d1['rating'] = d1.eval("x=x2/x1")['x'].apply(lambda r: get_rating(r, d2, formula))
```

Результат:

```
In [65]: d1
Out[65]:
     x1     x2  rating
0  16.0  500.0  0.0075
```